# Type of verb English grammar

Tags: verbs, usage

In examining the grammar of this sentence:

> Also, paragraph frames could be used with graphic organizers as
> appropriate.

is the verb 'used' transitive, or a linking verb?

Answer (score 1):

The verb phrase here is "could be used".  The word "could" is modal, and "be used" is the passive voice of the transitive verb "use"

In an active voice sentence, the "grammatical subject" (the noun phrase preceding the verb) is also the functional subject (the actor, the thing that performs the action referred to in the verb).  And the grammatical object (the noun phrase following the verb) is the functional object (the thing that receives the action or the effects of the action).

In the passive voice, the grammatical object is omitted and the grammatical subject is the functional object of the verb.  So the functional object is "paragraph frames".

So the verb is transitive, but in the passive voice, so there is no grammatical object.

This sentence is roughly equivalent to

> Also, [Teachers] could use paragraph frames with graphic organisers, as appropriate.

Filling in the implied subject with the explicit [Teachers].  This makes it clear that the verb is indeed transitive.